# How to get text from a QLineEdit in a different Qt plugin

Tags: c++, qt, interface, qlineedit, qtplugin

I have an interface `MyInterface`:

```
class MyInterface
{

public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}

    virtual QMap<QString, QString> *inputsMap() const = 0;
};
```

I have a class **MyImplementingClass** that implements `MyInterface`. However, I'm unable to get the text from `QLineEdit *fullNames`:

```
QLineEdit *fullNames = new QLineEdit();

QMap<QString, QString> *MyImplementingClass::inputsMap() const
{
    QMap<QString, QString> *map = new QMap<QString, QString>();
    map -> insert("fullNames", this -> fullNames -> text());
    map -> insert("coolText", "This works OK");
    return map;
}
```

In `ImplementorsCollector` is where I gather all the plugins that implement `MyInterface`:

```
void ImplementorsCollector :: initImplementors(QObject *plugin)
{
    MyInterface *iMyInterface = qobject_cast<MyInterface *>(plugin);
    if (iMyInterface)
        myObject = iMyInterface -> inputsMap();
}
```

However, still in `ImplementorsCollector`:

```
/* This prints nothing. Nothing gets passed from **QLineEdit *fullNames** */

if (myObject -> contains("fullNames"))
qDebug() << "fullNames : " << myObject -> value("fullNames");

/* This prints OK */

if (myObject -> contains("coolText"))
qDebug() << "coolText : " << myObject -> value("coolText");
```

How can I go about getting the text input from `**QLineEdit *fullNames**` from a different plugin?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you add `"fullNames"` , but check for `myObject -> contains("type")` ?

Comment: Sorry. That was an typo I made while trying to shorten the question. I have it right in my app, but it doesn't work.